# What does Keras Conv2d(3 ,64, 3, 1) mean?

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

What does the this `Conv2d(3, 64, 3, 1)` mean in Keras? the input is given as `(36, 64, 3)` and after the `Conv2d(3, 64, 3, 1)` layer the output is given as `(36, 64, 64)`.
Can anyone tell me if `Conv2d(a, b, c, d)` what the associated meanings of a, b, c and d are?

**EDIT:**: The documentation is stating the following:

```
Conv2d(filters, kernel_size, stride=(x,y), padding='valid', data_format=None, dilation_rate=(1, 1), activation=None, use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', 
bias_initializer='zeros', kernel_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None)
```

Does this mean that `Conv2d(3, 64, 3, 1)` has 3 filters, a kernel size of 64=8x8, stride = (3, 1)?

Comment: I'm not sure if you have already seen this or not, but the documentation has names for the parameters a, b, c, and d: https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/ Ctrl+F for Conv2d, for some stupid reason I can't link to the subsection.

Comment: Thank you @Dair. In the documentation they say `Conv2d(filters, kernel_size, stride=(x,y), padding='valid', data_format=None, dilation_rate=(1, 1), activation=None, use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros', kernel_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None)`. But there is not a good one-to-one correspondence to my model.

Comment: @MrYouMath Could you show this specific usage in the code? Since `Conv2D` in Keras can have at most 3 positional arguments, but in your example it has 4?!

Comment: @today It is a from a model that I found online.

Comment: @MrYouMath Could you run it on your machine? Please post the relevant portions in your question so that others can see it in the context. Further, what version of Keras is used in that tutorial?

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear about the function of each of these parameters. You should learn how CNNs work if they are still unclear

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking at a graph representation of a model.

Here `Conv2d(D, N, K, S)` denotes a 2D convolutional layer with kernel size KxK, stride S, input depth D and output depth (i.e. the number of conv kernels in this layer) N.

So in your case: input depth is 3, kernels are of size 3x3, stride=1 and there are 64 kernels, resulting in output of depth 64.